# Increment a alpha numerical string abcd1234 upto abcd2000 in c or c++

Tags: c++, c

Increment a alpha numerical string "abcd1234" upto "abcd2000"
output:
abcd1234
abcd1235
.
.
.
abcd2000

Comment: I'd also like to know why they downvoted this question. My guess is that the SO community really dislikes questions where you just ask for some code without showing any effort by yourself. Also it dislikes questions which are too specific (e.g. I have this problem, solve it)

Comment: @GiulioFranco The tooltip if you hover over the downvote button says “This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful”. Seems like a case of three out of three.

Comment: OK, done.  Now what?

Comment: You sir are definitely management material!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16770040/971127

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
for (int a = 1234; a <= 2000; ++a)
{
  std::cout << "abcd" << a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C,

```
for (int i=1234; i<= 2000;i++)
 printf("abcd%d\n",i);
```